# How to put multiple Facebook Like buttons with counter on same page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

I have one page with multiple news items. Every item in the list must have own [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) Like button with count.

**Is it possible to put multiple Like buttons with count for each news on same page?**

[image: Multiple Facebook like button with count on the same page]

Comment: do not mark this question down please.  I took the time to post the answer, this is a good question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each like button code will have to have it's own unique url.

refer to: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

> I use php to achieve this, by pulling all relative urls needed from a
>   database, looping them and writing return to the data-href param in
>   the html5 like button code.

You can manually set these links or set up a dynamic system as i did.

---

html5 button code.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="'.$thepage[link1].'" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="90" data-show-faces="false" data-font="tahoma" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;"></div>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="'.$thepage[link2].'" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="90" data-show-faces="false" data-font="tahoma" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;"></div>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="'.$thepage[link3].'" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="90" data-show-faces="false" data-font="tahoma" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;"></div>
```

---

xfbml button

```
<fb:like href="http://anotherfeed.com?link=1" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>

<fb:like href="http://anotherfeed.com?link=2" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>

<fb:like href="http://anotherfeed.com?link=3" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
```

Comment: Is it just me, or does this make Chromes memory usage skyrocket?